# Rotate a slice of CAShape layer as per dragging

Tags: ios, calayer, cashapelayer

How do i rotate a layer(CAShapeLayer) as one point as centre.

Check the image below for some more clear understanding of my Question.

[image]

I need to rotate the particular triangle layer alone while touches moved. Where the centre should not move.

If anyOne have ideas, Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Can you add the image to your post without the link and show us what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry brother not able to add image with the post. For adding the image in post i need 10 reputations.

Comment: I have added the image, can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: Shall i post the code in this comment

Comment: I got the result... Finished the task... Thanks... :)

Comment: Can you post the basics of your answer as well? :)

Comment: I am using angles for rotating the slice. I mean while touching the particular slice i will get the angle of that slice.. And then while dragging the slice i will increase the angle for clockwise and decrease the angle for anti-clockwise... using CABasicanimation.

Comment: U want me to post my code :)

Comment: Yes please. To help others with the same difficulties.

Comment: May i post with this comment or else in new post bro?

Comment: In this comment please. Or in this post is even better. :) You can edit your question, or post it as an answer if your reputation score allows it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your layer.anchorPoint.

You can read [THIS](http://ideveloper.co/understanding-the-anchor-point/) to understand anchorPoint.

Comment: Thank you brother... I had completed the task... But i got some ideas about anchor point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
double prevLayerRotationRadius;

  double StartToAngle;
  double EndToAngle;

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat seperateSliceStartAngle;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
           UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:View];
        [self performActionForSeperateSliceRotation:point];

}

#pragma mark - RotateSeperateLayers

-(void)performActionForSeperateSliceRotation:(CGPoint)point{
    double rotationRadius = atan2(  point.y -  _pieCenter.y , point.x - _pieCenter.x );

    if (rotationRadius <=0) {
        rotationRadius =  radian180 + (radian180 - ABS(rotationRadius));
    }
    if (prevLayerRotationRadius && prevLayerRotationRadius !=0) {

        double radiusDiff = (rotationRadius  - prevLayerRotationRadius);

        if (radiusDiff <=0) {
            radiusDiff = ABS(radiusDiff) - ABS ((int)radiusDiff ) ;

            _SliceStartAngle = _SliceStartAngle - ABS(radiusDiff);


        }else {
            radiusDiff = ABS(radiusDiff) - ABS ((int)radiusDiff ) ;

            _SliceStartAngle = _SliceStartAngle + ABS(radiusDiff);

        }
        [self rotateSeperateLayers:_SliceStartAngle];

    }

    prevLayerRotationRadius = rotationRadius;

}

- (void)rotateSeperateLayers:(float)sperateSliceAngle{

    StartToAngle = 2.660850; // Angle of particular Piece (To get in angle use R2D)
    EndToAngle = StartToAngle;

    double angle = [[self.sliceAngleArray objectAtIndex:selectedBeganPanLayerOne]doubleValue];
    EndToAngle += angle;

    double startFromAngle = 2.660850;
    double endFromAngle = 2.660850;

    [Layer createArcAnimationForKey:@"startAngle"
                          fromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:startFromAngle]
                            toValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:StartToAngle+SliceAngle]
                           Delegate:self];
    [Layer createArcAnimationForKey:@"endAngle"
                          fromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:endFromAngle]
                            toValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:EndToAngle+SliceAngle]
                           Delegate:self];

}

- (void)createArcAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key fromValue:(NSNumber *)from toValue:(NSNumber *)to Delegate:(id)delegate
{
    CABasicAnimation *arcAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:key];
    NSNumber *currentAngle = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key];

    if(!currentAngle) currentAngle = from;

    [arcAnimation setFromValue:currentAngle];
    [arcAnimation setToValue:to];         
    [arcAnimation setDelegate:delegate];
    [arcAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
    [self addAnimation:arcAnimation forKey:key];
    [self setValue:to forKey:key];
}
```